# Grails Enum location

Tags: grails, enums

I'n new to Grails and I'm building an app with mapped classes and some auxiliar Enums.
I'm not sure where in the project those Enums should be, I've seen people having them in the "domain" folder of the project and come others have them in src/groovy.
I'd guess the former one is for mapped Enums, but I couldn't find a clear explanation.

Extra fact: I currently have my enums inside the "domain" folder. They are not mapped (or I least I don't need to), they are used as attributes in other mapped domain classes. It works fine in GGTS except when I change an Enum with the app running, then I get a "It is not a Domain!" exception, so I guess I'm not using my Enums in the correct way.

Comment: It's not common an issue with the ide placing the enums into the domains folder. Show us the enum class, for make us easier to helping you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be in either place, and will not be mapped to database tables like classes since GORM knows that they're just enums. As you've seen, they can be mapped properties.

I think people tend to keep them with domain classes if that's the only place in the app that they're used, although they can be accessed from outside of domain classes since they're compiled regardless of their location.

So it comes down to preference. Keep them in `src/groovy` since they're not domain classes, or keep them where they're used. Your choice :)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty clear. I guess the exception I'm getting is an IDE problem.